# How do my java method return true when it found array elements index is prime

Tags: java, arrays

I have a java method like

```
void getSumAtPrime(int[] n, int n_limit){

System.out.println("limit:"+n_limit);
for(int j=0; j<n_limit; j++){ 

 if(getPrime(j)){

System.out.println(n[j]);
}
}
```

Which will print prime indexed array elements using `getPrime()`

and my getPrime() method is like

```
boolean getPrime(int numi){

 boolean flag=false; 
 for(int i=2;i<numi;i++){ 
    if(numi%i==0) { 
 flag = true; 
 break; 
 } 
 } 
 return flag;
 }
```

but now it is only printing numbers from 5 for example if i enter 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 it will print 5,7,8. I couldn't find the problem, someone please help me to fix this

Comment: What happens when you tried to debug your program? I'm not sure if you use well your `getPrime` method. It seems like it returns true to indicates that the number is NOT prime but you consider the inverse.

Comment: Note that you're printing some indexes and not the *prime* numbers.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ya i am printing some indexes but it is starting from 5 why?

Comment: @user3649895 I have no idea what are these indexes, your question is not clear.

Comment: @user3649895 Because the first number superior than 2 that is not prime is 4, which corresponds to the value 5 in your array.

Comment: @ZouZouI am using the same logic from this program http://pastebin.com/i7UyJ5ti and this program return the perfect output

Comment: @user3649895 _"Which will print prime indexed array elements"_  Your `getPrime` method returns `true` if the number is NOT prime (like in the program you linked), but you are using it like if it returns true, it means that the number IS prime for you.

Comment: @MarounMaroun i want to print elements from an integer array if its index in that array is a prime number

Comment: @user3649895 Your code works fine then. Show example please.

Comment: `i want to print elements from an integer array if its index in that array is a prime number` and how does your array looks like?

Comment: @ZouZou: is my logic correct?

Comment: @user3649895 No your logic is not correct. You need to do `if(!getPrime(j))` and add additional case in your `getPrime` method to return true for the numbers 0 and 1 and false for the number 2. OR the better way, flip the return value of the `getPrime` method to return true IF the element is a prime number.

Comment: @Pshemo my array is an integer-array it looks like{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

Comment: @user3649895 What output do you expect when calling `getPrime(5)`?

Comment: @ZouZou: It works thank you, post your answer please

Comment: @ZouZou: Sorry about my bad english

Comment: @user3649895 You can accept one of the above post that shows you how to write a proper method that checks if the number is prime or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean getPrime(int p){
if(p < 2) return false;
if(p == 2 || p == 3) return true;
if(p % 2 == 0) return false;

  for(int i = 3; i <= Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(p)); i += 2){ 
    if(p % i == 0) { 
      return false;
    } 
  } 
  return true;
}
```

Comment: `if its index in that array is a prime number`

Comment: Ah sorry diden't see that my bad.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
void getSumAtPrime(int[] n, int n_limit) {
  System.out.println("limit:"+n_limit);
  for(int j=0; j < n_limit; j++) { 
    if(getPrime(j))
      System.out.println(j + " : " + n[j]);
  }
} 



boolean getPrime(int numi) {
  if ( n < 2) return false;    
  for(int i=2; i < numi; i++)
    if(numi%i==0) return false; 
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was why you are getting 5 as the first output.

Well because in your getPrime method, you are checking `if(numi%i==0)` . Which will be true for 2,4,6 and 8.

Now, in your for loop you have `for(int i=2;i<numi;i++){` so "2" is not satisfying the `i<num1` check.

So we get 4,6,8 indices for which the method returns true.

Now, you are printing n[j], so you get

> n[4] = 5 n[6] = 7 n[8] = 9

What is the concern now?

> P.s I just answered the doubt. Whether whatever you are doing is
>   correct or not, is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

```
void getSumAtPrime(int[] n, int n_limit){

System.out.println("limit:"+n_limit);
for(int j=0; j<n_limit; j++){ 

 if(getPrime(j)){

System.out.println(n[j]);
}
}
//method to get prime or not
public boolean  getPrime(int numi){
        int  i, res;
        boolean flag=true;      
        for(i=2;i<=numi/2;i++)
        {
            res=numi%i;
            if(res==0)
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return flag;
}
```